# How to lock a layer in Sony Vegas?

Tags: video, video-processing, editing, sony

While working with layers in Sony Vegas, one usually sometimes wants to clip a certain part in a particular layer. When I make a selection all the layers get selected and deleted parallely. Is there a way to select the "only desired" layer for a operation or to lock the other layers.

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean by "lip", but I am thinking that "Options > Ignore Event Grouping" will do what you want. Or if you want to remove a whole track just click the track header (on the left) and press the Del key (or right click and select "Delete Track").

Comment: I meant 'clip'. Typo corrected

Comment: Cut or Delete operate on a combination of time selection and event selection. So select just the events you was to cut out before doing the cut.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all events on the track.
2. Right click on one of the selected events.
3. Select Switches -> Lock. 
   this might help you.